# How can I extend UiApp with a new function?

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to extend (prototype) UiApp in Google Apps Script with a wrapping function, but I am getting TypeError when running a simple sample like below... 
what am I doing wrong?

```
Object.prototype.addLabel = function(text) {   
  this.createLabel(text);
  return this;
}

function testingxUiApp() {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('playing around UiApp').setHeight("250");
  var panel = app.createFlowPanel().setId('panel');
  app.add(panel);
  panel.add(app.addLabel("adding label for testing"));
  doc.show(app);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Great question! {The general problem, so for not just UiApp but for any Google class in GAS}  I cover & answer in detail at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432951/how-to-extend-google-apps-script-classes/30539765#30539765 , including with references to this answer here and all other answers for this I've encountered; so, if that could help you, I'd recommend seeing my answer there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Class UiApp is deprecated. Reference https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is impossible to extend UiApp, Document, Spreadsheet and other high order classes. Google prevented it. If to execute the `var isObject = UiApp.createApplication() instanceof Object;` line then the `isObject` is false, although the `typeof UiApp.createApplication();` expression returns `object`.

Comment: thanks, it's good to know even when it's no good news, like this case

Comment: Certainly good to know, thanks, that was my goal and I'm stubborn so it would been painful ^^

Answer (score 0):

BTW note from 2021: (from https://b.corp.google.com/issues/36753527)

It looks like Reflect used in V8 can do the trick:

```
  Reflect.set(
    Reflect.getPrototypeOf(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Some sheet')),
    'myMethod',
    function() {
      return `From sheet '${this.getSheetName()}' with love`;
    }
  );

  let message = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().myMethod();
  console.log(message); // From sheet 'Sheet1' with love`
```